# Mysql Check 2 columns of 11 row value is grater than 5

Tags: mysql

Have scores of a batsman stored in the table for team

table has columns as

```
team_id
batsman_id
score
```

How to check if all batsman in team scored greater than say 5 runs

Comment: Get teams where there is at least one batsman with the score below the criteria. Get teams not listed in previous output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the minimum score of each team if it is greater than 5:

```
select team_id, 
       min(score) > 5 all_above_5 -- you will get 1 or 0
from tablename
group by team_id
```

If you want only the teams that *all batsman in team scored greater than say 5 runs*:

```
select team_id
from tablename
group by team_id
having min(score) > 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
SELECT team_id,
CASE 
   WHEN min_scr <6 then 'have <6 score'
   ELSE 'everyone scored more than 5' as Result 
FROM
(SELECT team_id,min(score) AS min_scr FROM score_tbl GROUP BY team_id)
```

With this, you will get list of teams in which at least one batmen have scored less than 6.

We can add other filters or manipulate results as required, but we will get each team level results by using above query.